# Which one is faster; Shared Preference or Sqlite Database

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-layout, sharedpreferences

This seems to be a common question, but i am unable to find out a straight away answer.

I get `JSONObject` from server, each activity needs to access it and get some data from it, that's the reason i am more concerned about the performance here.

This is what i do. Following operation runs for each activity.

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
dataObject = db.getAllData();
jsonObject = new JSONObject(dataObject );
value = jsonObject.optString(key);
```

The data is pretty straight forward, its a simple `JsonObject`, i can also put this in `sharedPreference`, but before moving to `sharedPreference`, i want to be sure that `sharedPreference` are faster than `sqlite database`, or moving to `sharedPreference` can give me performance improvement.

Comment: Yes I think it will give you a better performance and async handling of saving data with .apply() instead of .commit() the only perk I see is the quantity of data you store in sharedPreferences

Answer (score -1):

If **your data Are low and only type text**, surely the variable is the best option

Otherwise, if **your data is large and are many and different**, you should use powerful Android databases like : MySqlite , Realm , ...